# is there any solution for how to convert decimal values and alphanumeric in integer type in pyspark

Tags: pyspark-schema

ex: act: salesorgcode:    Reqired
6001.0           6001
9001.0           9001
7002.0           7002
A001             A001
T001             T001

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
salesorgcode = [("Finance",6001.0), 
            ("Marketing",9001.0), 
            ("Sales",7002.0), 
            ("IT",8002.0) 
          ]
    salesColumns = ["sales_name","sales_id"]
    salesDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=salesorgcode, schema = salesColumns)
    data_df = salesDF.withColumn("sales_id", salesDF["sales_id"].cast(IntegerType()))
    
    data_df.show(truncate=False)


+----------+--------+
|sales_name|sales_id|
+----------+--------+
|Finance   |6001    |
|Marketing |9001    |
|Sales     |7002    |
|IT        |8002    |
+----------+--------+
```